# Change button size while button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

My Question is how can i change the size of a button while the finger is hovering over it?

Sorry if this Question is already answered but i didn't found any results for me.
Please link the Thread as an answer if its already answered :)

I already tried it with a UIView and then listening with a CGRectIntersectsRect if it touches the button. But i think theres a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: hovering doesn't do work on a touch screen, you have to touch it.  Use the touch down event as suggested below.

Comment: oh im sorry. i meant touching it. but like UIControlEventTouchDown and not UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Comment: I thought that might be what you meant :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method that observes that event. The one you're looking for, I think, is UIControlEventTouchDown

```
- (void)initOrSomething {
    UIButton *button = ...
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

- (void)buttonPress:(UIButton *)button {
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

If you add yourself as a target, you should be able to change the frame in the your selector.

Comment: Sure, the only thing I thought I might mention is that changing the frame may (I haven't tested, so I'm not sure) cause you to lose your event, especially if you make the frame smaller.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    CGRect f = self.button2.frame;
    f.origin.x += 10;
    f.size.width += 10; 
    self.button2.frame = f;
}
```

Add this action with UIControlEventTouchDown.

Hope this helps...

Comment: i dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
    pressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.0;
    pressGesture.delegate = self;
    [_button addGestureRecognizer: pressGesture];
    ...
}


- (void)buttonPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)rec {
    switch (rec.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations: ^{
                 _button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
             }];
             break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: 
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations: ^{
                 _button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
             }];
             break;
        default: 
             break;
    }

}
```

This basically animates the button to shrink while the user holds down onto the button. And when the finger's lifted, the button size go back to original size.